# How to write an API that accepts a series of anonymous dictionary items?

Tags: c#, dictionary, anonymous-types

I frequently find myself needing to write APIs that involve key value pairs, when I work with this generally I'll end up with a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` or similar type collection object which lets me write operations very easily.

The only downside I've come across is adding multiple items to this collect usually results in a very noisy code block such as

```
MyDictionary.Put(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a","1"), 
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b","2"), 
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("c","3"))
```

I would much rather be able to do

```
MyDictionary.Put( {"a","1"},  {"b","2"},  {"c","3"})
```

A few times I've tried to accomplish and always end up stumbling over what C# expects exactly as the syntax for this.

Answer (score 4):

Collection initialisers allow much of that;

```
var data = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    {"a","1"},
    {"b","2"},
    {"c","3"}
};
```

Another way to approach this is to pass just `object` an use reflection, passing (for example):

```
new { a = "1", b = "2", c = "3" }
```

A nice feature of the last option is that you can also pass in your domain entities, and you can perhaps use richer metadata (attributes etc) - but **when used in high volume** reflection *by itself* can be slow unless you take steps to optimise for it. If you aren't using it in a tight loop it should be ok even *with* reflection (and without optimisation).

Comment: I suppose I could make the parameter type be a `dictionary<string,string>` and then iterate over it to add the items to my collection.

Comment: Down side to using the full out dictionary is I end up with `Put( { {"a","1"},  {"b","2"},  {"c","3"} } )` which is just a new kind of noise. I'm really trying to figure this out in regards to the params keyword.

Comment: @chris - there is no half-way that let's you use params and the collection-initializer syntax, I'm afraid

Comment: @Chris - I would give serious consideration to the anon-type approach. It would be only a few moments work to write a PropertiesToDictionary method that the caller can use to translate - and the callers all get very clean syntax.

Comment: The anonymous class method only works when your strings are valid identifiers.

Comment: I don't think the anonymous object would work since the values that would become the identifiers are parameter names which are all in a constants file.

Answer (score 1):

For literals, how about ...

```
MyDictionary.Put("a=1", "b=2", "c=3");
```

implemented something like ...

```
void Put(params string[] nameEqualValues)
{
    foreach (string nameEqualValue in nameEqualValues)
    {
        int iEquals = nameEqualValue.IndexOf('=');
        if (iEquals < 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(...);
        }
        string name = nameEqualValue.Substring(0, iEquals);
        string val = nameEqualValue.Substring(iEquals + 1);

        this.PutNameValue(name, val);
    }
}
```

Combining and then splitting strings is a bit of overhead, but it doesn't sound as though performance is a critical concern.

Mind you this breaks down if you're not dealing with literals, worse than what you started with ...

```
MyDictionary.Put(d + "=" + x, e + "=" + y);
MyDictionary.Put(String.Format("{0}={1}", d, x), ...);
```

I'd probably suck it up and stick with "params string[]", or call Put multiple times. (Or use python ;)

Comment: +1 for thinking out of the box, I like the idea but as you said it breaks down with nonliterals which is what I would use this for, mashing a constant key with a runtime value.

Answer (score 1):

Require that params come in pairs and treat evens (zero, two, ...) as keys and odds as values:

```
void Put(params string[] items)
{
    if (items.Length % 2 != 0) throw new ArgumentException("Expected even number");

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i += 2)
    {
        this.myDict[items[i]] = items[i+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for another idea, this one definitely has potential, it would be some what strange behavior implied by this method but so far this is the most optimal for actual usage where it would come out as `dict.Put(ConstantKey1, xval, ConstantKey2, yval)`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out a very clean way of doing this, but one workaround for lesser typing can be:

```
public class MyDictionary : List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    ...

    public void Put(params string[][] p)
    {
        foreach (var a in p)
            Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a[0], a[1]));
    }
}
```

which can be called like this:

```
MyDictionary.Put(new[] {"a", "1"}, new[] {"b", "2"}, new[] {"c", "3"});
```

But this is a definite memory waste and also very inefficient coding.

Comment: +1 for another idea, but it just trades 1 kind of noise for another